# How does one compare Monero's hashrate with the hash generating power of the world's supercomputers?

Tags: hashrate-comparison, monero-network-hashrate

Now I know that it is not a genuine 1:1 comparison but this was often a comparison used for fun to try and comprehend just how much computing power the Bitcoin network was comparatively generating.

If the worlds top 100 supercomputers were suddenly to start mining on the Monero network, what kind of hashrate would it theoretically be generating, and how does that compare to the current hashrate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two months ago, Monero core developer smooth [said](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4kop0o/laymans_question_regarding_monero_ranking/d3ibhmp):

> Monero's mining network is comparable to a low top-10 supercomputer. It's not invulnerable to all attackers but it is a significant amount of security relative to the value of the coin and what could be achieved by attacking it.

Over the past two months Monero hashrate has grown about [50%](http://www.coinwarz.com/network-hashrate-charts/monero-network-hashrate-chart). The worlds top 100 supercomputers would have the ability to capture a very large majority of the Monero network hashrate. It would be expensive to attack Monero (relative to its current marketcap) but far from impossible at this time.